# ListViewItem content is not stretching when using a DataTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, stretch

My ListView is not behaving as I want and I can't seem to find anything useful on this topic.
So the problem is, that I have a ListView which uses a DataTemplateSelector based on Datatype.
So this all works fine and shows the correct control, but the problem is, that the items do not stretch horizontally!
All solutions regardings ListViewItems not stretching suggest to use

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

and to set

```
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

in the ListView.

This does work fine when no DataTemplateSelector is used, but in combination with that DataTemplateSelector it doesn't and the controls in the list do not get their parents size.
The DataTemplateSelector is by the book and works fine, so it is omitted here.
I tried all kind of combinations of Width="Auto", HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment, but I could not make it work. I could imagine that it might help to pass the Width or HorizontalContentAlignment in this DataTemplateSelector, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Here is the minimal XAML:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DrawDataTemplate" DataType="viewModels:DrawSectionViewModel">
      <infrastructure:DrawSectionItem />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FeedDataTemplate" DataType="viewModels:FeedSectionViewModel">
      <infrastructure:FeedSectionItem />
    </DataTemplate>

    <infrastructure:SectionTemplateSelector x:Key="SectionTemplateSelector"
                                            FeedSection="{StaticResource FeedDataTemplate}" 
                                            DrawSection="{StaticResource DrawDataTemplate}">
    </infrastructure:SectionTemplateSelector>

  </UserControl.Resources>

<ListView Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding LeftSections }"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SectionTemplateSelector}"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Added the item controls. The Draw section is pretty much the same structure.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Infrastructure.FeedSectionItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="45" Width="188" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Background="Black"
              >

    <Grid Margin="0" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto">
            <TextBlock Text="Feed" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" />
            <TextBlock Text="" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </StackPanel>       
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Could you share xaml for infrastructure:DrawSectionItem and infrastructure:FeedSectionItem?

Comment: Added it to the main question

Comment: Try to remove Width="188" from your UserControl.

Comment: Removing the width from the UserControl indeed does work! I would however only consider this a workaround, since now I can't really design my UserControl anymore because it shrinks automatically as no width is set. Setting the Grid to a width brings me back to the initial problem.  I could remove the width each time after designing the Control... works, but does not appear to be a clean solution for a theoretically easy problem.

Comment: Ok in that second a good workaround came to my mind, which is to add a MinWidth to the Control. Then it has a width which can be used for design and the actual width in the ListView is also working as expected.

Comment: You can use d:DesignWidth to set the width of the user control for design.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Width="188"` from your `UserControl`.

In the designer you can set `d:DesignWidth="188"`